# php xpath returning entire html

Tags: php, html, xpath, curl, screen-scraping

why is this returning the whole html document instead of just the values from nodes that contain "H+R+E"?

sample of html:

```
<tr class="linesAlt1">
        <td>04:10 PM</td><td style="width:53%;">3055&nbsp;Over</td><td style="width:22%;">3&nbsp;H+R+E&nbsp;&nbsp;+146</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to just get `"3&nbsp;H+R+E&nbsp;&nbsp;+146"`. but this dumps all html.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.pinnaclesports.com/ContestCategory/MLB+Propositions/July+13~2C~+2012/Lines.aspx';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("//table/tr/td[contains(., 'H+R+E')]") as $textNode){
  echo $textNode->nodeValue."\n";
}


?>
```

Comment: possibly has to do with namespace? "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl_exec` prints to `STDOUT` by default, which is what you're seeing. In other words, you're not capturing any output in `$html` (or printing anything in that loop). First, you need to redirect the output:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
```

After fixing that issue, I looked at the source of the URL provided and can't find that text -- `H+R+E` -- anywhere in it. It has one table, but not with that content. You're looking for something that isn't there.

To prove that it's now correctly retrieving the file, try this complete example:

```
$url = 'http://www.pinnaclesports.com/ContestCategory/MLB+Propositions/July+13~2C~+2012/Lines.aspx';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen('php://stdout', 'w'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$html = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("//table") as $table){
      echo "[" . $table->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

...which produces the following output (`loadHTML` warnings omitted):

```
[
                    Client ID:




                    Password:
```

More information about setting cURL options:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php

Comment: thanks. i realized that the source was a bad example after posting because they take down that info at night... not sure how else i woulda explained this unless i just copied the whole source from earlier today.